# intersection between a geometry and a layer in Arcobjects VBA

Tags: arcobjects, vba

i have to make an intersection between a polygon and a layer of parcels, the polygon used in the clip is not belonging to any layer and the result of this intersection should be all the parcels inside and cuted by the polygon (clip) so i thought to use ITopologicalOperator but i haven't understood how to work with this tool , also it seems to give one feature as result but in my case i need a set of features.

can you give me the right tool to use in Arcobject for my case ?

any advice is welcome :)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a spatial filter (ISpatialFilter) with the geometry and get a featurecursor for the layer (using IFeatureclass.Search).  Cast the search geometry to ITopologicalOperator and call Intersect on each IFeature.Shape returned by IFeatureCursor.Next().

Comment: thanks for your help , i was very useful :) , but i'm still stuck with creating new layer in arc objects , i have tried this code it do not work i have a bug in the line with #

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help , it was very useful :) , but i'm still stuck with creating new layer where i could put the result of the intersection, i have tried this code but it do not work i have a bug in the line with #

code

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Set pSpatialFilter = New SpatialFilter
Set pSpatialFilter.Geometry = pPoly 'the polygone clip
pSpatialFilter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelContains
Set pUpdateCursor = fcpu.Update(pSpatialFilter, False)
Set pTopOp = pPoly
Set pFeature = pUpdateCursor.NextFeature

Dim geom As IGeometry
 Dim fe As IFeature

' get the workspace and start editing

Dim fcout As IFeatureClass
Dim pNewWSName As IWorkspaceName
Dim pFeatClassName As IFeatureClassName
Dim pDatasetName As IDatasetName
Set pFeatClassName = New FeatureClassName
Set pDatasetName = pFeatClassName

Set pNewWSName = New WorkspaceName
pNewWSName.WorkspaceFactoryProgID = _
"esriCore.ShapeFileWorkspaceFactory"
pNewWSName.PathName = "c:\"
Set pDatasetName.WorkspaceName = pNewWSName
pDatasetName.Name = "Intersect_result"

Dim pFName As IName
  Set pFName = pFeatClassName

Set fcout = pFName.Open  # ' here it stops
    Dim pDataset As IDataset
  Set pDataset = fcout

Dim pWorkspace As IWorkspace
  Set pWorkspace = pDataset.Workspace

Dim pWorkspaceEdit As IWorkspaceEdit
  Set pWorkspaceEdit = pWorkspace

pWorkspaceEdit.StartEditing True
  pWorkspaceEdit.StartEditOperation

'''''''''''''''

Dim pFeat As IFeature
  Dim pRow As IRow
  Dim pFlds As IFields
  Dim lSFld As Long
  Dim i As Long

Do Until pFeature Is Nothing

'Set fe = New Feature

'Set geom = pTopOp.Intersect(pFeature.Shape, esriGeometry1Dimension)

Set pFeat = fcout.CreateFeature
'fcout.Fields = pFeat.Fields

' Set pFlds = pFeat.Fields
   ' For i = 0 To pFlds.FieldCount - 1

'     lSFld = pFeature.Fields.FindField(pFlds.Field(i).Name)

```
'    pFeat.Value(i) = pFeature.Value(lSFld)
```

'  Next i

Set pFeat.Shape = pTopOp.Intersect(pFeature.Shape, esriGeometry1Dimension)
    pFeat.Store
Set pFeature = pUpdateCursor.NextFeature
Loop
      pWorkspaceEdit.StopEditOperation
  pWorkspaceEdit.StopEditing True

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there, instead of answering your own question with a new question.